# Java OSGi Centralised Network Configuration

Tags: java, networking, osgi

I'm looking to create an app based on the OSGi model. One of the elements of this will be network access (http and obr initially)

I am looking for a way of centralising the network config (proxying, encryption, etc) perhaps to a single bundle that the rest of the app can call into.

Has anybody done this/got ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you only want to centralize the network-related configuration or you want to create a service that would be used for all network access operations (i.e. also centralize the network access code)?

Comment: Ideally centralise the access code as well, so everything can use the same interface for any kind of network access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case one possibility would be to create an OSGi service or a set of services (possibly encapsulated in a separate bundle) that would provide all the required network access methods. The service(s) themselves could be configured through [Configuration Admin Service](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v401/org/osgi/service/cm/package-summary.html) that is part of *OSGi Service Compendium*.

Some of the methods provided by the service(s) can actually be factory methods for creating pre-configured network access objects like [java.net.URLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) or [java.net.Socket](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html). Example:

```
public interface NetworkService {
    public Socket createSocket();
}

class NetworkServiceImpl implements NetworkService {
    static final Proxy DEFAULT_PROXY = new Proxy(...);

    public Socket createSocket() {
        Socket s = new Socket(DEFAULT_PROXY);
        s.setReceiveBufferSize(4096);
        return s;
    } 
}
```